# Define the fade in fade out frames in matlab

Tags: matlab, image-processing, video-processing

I've got a frame in JPEG format.
I want to define if it's a fade in/out frame(which most of them are black frames) or not.
I read an article and tried to do exactly like that, but it wont work properly.
this is the idea:
At first the frame feature vector should be defined:
color histogram is computed only from the Hue component, which represents the dominant spectral component color in its pure form (Manjunath et al., 2001). Moreover, the quantization of the color histogram is set to 16 color bins, aiming at reducing significantly the amount of data without loosing important information
then it computes the standard deviation of the frame feature vector. The standard deviation of monochromatic frames is equal to zero or a sufficiently small value close to zero.4 This information is used by VSUMM to removes these frames. This step is also employed by Furini et al. (2010). 
The code is in MATLAB:

```
str = num2str(50);
filename1=strcat('pics\' , str , '.jpeg');
Im1 = imread(filename1);
hsv = rgb2hsv(Im1);
hn1 = hsv(:,:,1);
hn1 = hn1/norm(hn1);
f=std2(hn1)
```

According to the idea `f` should be  equal to zero or a sufficiently small value close to zero. it's correct for all fade in/out frame but the result is sometimes small value close to zero for usual frame which is wrong ,what is wrong with it? 
As an example i upload 4 pictures:
the result for the fisrt two pics which are fade in/out frames are 9.3340e-04,9.9959e-04 and for the 3rd image which is a normal frame is 0.23 which all of these results are correct but then the result for some frames like the 4th one which is a normal frames is 8.2447e-04 which is wrong.
honestly this code is n't that important, i just want a code that distinguish normal frames from fade in/out frames.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: No one can answer?<br> Is my question clear?

Comment: Perhaps you can post an example false positive image. Otherwise there is no way for anyone to determine what the appropriate metric is...